# How to repair a plaster crack over brick that is a hard wall

Tags: repair, brick, plaster, crack

I am trying to determine what fill to use in a plaster crack. The plaster is directly over brick. This wall is also an outdoor wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Crack on plasterwall under window]

Comment: A picture and a description of what you mean by "hard wall" would help in answering your question. The size and character of the crack matter.

Comment: I might be using the wrong term. Basically it is a wall that faces outside.  It is not an interior wall in the house. The interior walls are plaster over Sheetrock. The walls facing the outside of the house are just plaster on brick.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with this as well, but there are quite a few similar questions answered on this stack that you can search for to get a range of ideas.

First note that it looks like this was patched before, which could indicate a more serious underlying problem that patching won't solve, and may deserve attention (e.g. water issues).

1. Remove any loose material in the crack using some tool (plaster knife, screwdriver, etc.)
2. Wet the old plaster with water (e.g. spray bottle), this prevents it from absorbing too much moisture from the joint compound to improve the bond.
3. Fill large/deep cracks with a setting-type joint compound. If really deep, use can backfill with backer rod, or push in small strips or loops of mesh tape for some extra strength.
4. Setting-type or regular joint compound can be used to fill small/shallow cracks. I recommend combining this with paper tape (wet first) or mesh tape (requires more feathering but easier to apply).
5. Multiple passes might be required with some knocking down of high spots and some sanding as you finish it to your acceptable level - usually using a larger and larger knife (up to say 12" on either side) as you feather outward to hide the repair.
6. Once it all dries, clean gently to remove dust from the surface (a very slightly damp cloth/sponge - wipe too hard and you can pull material off).
7. Prime (very helpful for freshly mudded areas) and paint.

Depending on how nice you want it to look and your skill level, you may find the finishing stage to be a real pain - I know I did.

Comment: I recall a YouTube video repairing a plaster surface, where the guy primed the wall with glue and mixed glue with the setting type compound for better adhesion. I inferred that delamination of the setting type compound from the plaster was a pitfall. Was he maybe not doing it right by not priming the surface with water like you suggest? Is a paint primer before applying compound maybe a good idea to improve the bond?

Comment: Adding the right kind of glue probably reduces this risk of problems. There are adhesives/additives designed for use with concrete and mortar that are probably appropriate. I can't say if they are needed or just belt and suspenders - beyond my diy experience. I have not needed them myself, but my walls and local environment could be more in my favor than someone else's.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.  I fell down the rabbit whole of the internet and I think I was just over thinking it.  I am also saw the glue video. I am going to go with setting joint compound and mesh tape and add the glue as well. (I also saw that video).  Wish me luck and thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and you are correct about the underlying condition. But I had that fixed first.  